# Choosing a reference group among categorical fixed variables in a linear mixed effects model

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, mixed-model

I am working on a project that uses a linear mixed effects model for its main analysis. I am looking at the impact of situations on 'trait' and the random effects variables are participant ids (pID) -- level 2, and situation ids (sID) -- level 1. X (level 2), y (level 1), domain (level 1), and gender (level 2) are fixed variables.

```
library(nlme)
results<-lme(trait ~ domain*x*y + gender, data, random = list(~ 1 | pID,~ 1 | sID))
```

My issue is that while x, y, and gender, have reference groups that make sense or are dichotomous, the 'domain' variable is a bit different. These situations are categorized into 8 categorical domains, and each of these domains are completely equal to one another. When one domain vs another is chosen as a reference group in the model, all of the results change (as expected) as do the conclusions of the study.

I have no theoretical rationale to choose a given domain as a reference group, and even when I set the intercept to 0, the interaction effects still select a domain as a reference group.

```
results<-lme(trait ~ 0 + domain*x*y + gender, data, random = list(~ 1 | pID,~ 1 | sID))
```

Is there a way to use the average trait score across domains as a reference group? If not, is there another suggestion or best practice for this type of situation?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and expertise!

Comment: try `contrasts=list(domain=contr.sum)` ?

Comment: Thank you, Ben, for the suggestion. Based on your comment, I found the UCLA website (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm#DEVIATION) that explains the type of contrast coding being used, and found that the 'contr.Sum' function in the 'car' package allows you to keep the variable names. However, the last domain is still always set to '-1' in the contrasts and therefore that level is not included among the fixed factors estimates. Is there a way to include them all when comparing to the average mean per level?